# What is the difference between flash(a, b) and flash().put(a, b) in PlayFramework?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

In terms of a implementation of flash message in Play, I saw two ways.
Those are `flash(flashKey, flashMessage)` and `flash().put(flashKey, flashMessage)` where both `flashKey` and `flashMessage` are `String`.
What exactly is the difference?

Comment: where are you seeing `flash().put` can you provide a reference? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaSessionFlash#Flash-scope

Comment: oh i see -- java https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/d43e3e48e7ba6cd1551e3726bd3583a7b13563a2/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/mvc/Http.java#L2011

Answer (score 0):

`flash().put(key, message)` is the Flash class interface for adding the given value the flash scope

`flash(key, message)` is the RequestBuilder interface for updating the flash session. Under the hood it does exactly the same as `new HashMap<>(flash()).put(key, message)` ([source here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/d43e3e48e7ba6cd1551e3726bd3583a7b13563a2/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/mvc/Http.java#L1352)) but it looks like it does the additional step of updating the request cookies

I believe you should use `flash(key, message)` to ensure that any updates to the flash are persisted.

Comment: In short, `flash().put(key, message)` just adds the given value to the flash scope whereas `flash(key, message)` can add the value and update the user's cookie, right?  If so, how do you interpret this code( I am so sorry that it is a little difficult to see)        `ctx().flash().put(flashKey, flashMessage);`   And after this, redirect is done. I assume before adding the value there is no value in Map, so the redirect page has no choice but to use the value.